# I am getting "object reference not set to instance of object error"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following is the code to modify data using entity framework

```
int idtoupdate = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["EmpId"]);

EmployeeEntities db = new EmployeeEntities();

Employee emp = db.Employees.SingleOrDefault(p => p.EmpId == idtoupdate);
```

I am getting error for below line.......

```
emp.EmpLoc = TextBox1.Text;
Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(emp.EmpId);
Label4.Text = emp.EmpName;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: yes m using try catch block for null reference exception but then the values for label2 and label4 are not displaying

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you don't have `Employee` with `EmpId == idtoupdate` in your database. Before using `emp.EmpLoc` you have to check is `emp` is `null`:

```
if (emp != null) {
  emp.EmpLoc = TextBox1.Text;
  Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(emp.EmpId);
  Label4.Text = emp.EmpName;
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```